# Matlab: Updating max count in a loop doesn't work

Tags: matlab, loops

I have executed this simple loop script in MATLAB

```
clc;clear; close all;
m = 100;
for i = 1:m
    if(i == 2)
        m = 1000;
    end
end
```

and found, that 'i' loops only till '100' BUT NOT '1000'. Why..??

Comment: Read about [for](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html), especially the last section. _Avoid assigning a value to the index variable within the loop statements. The for statement overrides any changes made to index within the loop._

Comment: Is this really what you want? Or do you actually want to do something else?

Comment: @Bernhard: Yeah this is what I wanted. :)

Comment: @GautamKrishna No, in that case just put `m=1000` and remove the `if`.

Comment: Conditional number of iterations in a for loop would be a no-no if it existed. It would be a for-while serving to discretely make the programmers go banana. I do not want to be rude, but this would have the same dignity as `#define true false` or `#define SQUARE(a) (a*a)`

Comment: @patrik: what's the problem with SQUARE(a)?

Comment: @Jonas that's the problem :) people will never find out what the problem is apart from that the results are wrong. Assume a call `double x = 0; double y = SQUARE(x+1);`. This will be equivalent to `double y = x+1*x+1 == 2*x+1 != (x+1)^2`. Assume the resulting expression would be a second order equation? Hehe it is so terribly evil :). Anyway the proper definition is `#define SQUARE(a) ((a)*(a))`.

Comment: @patrik: TIL. Thanks for taking the time to reveal your evil schemes :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement `for i=1:m` assigns the array `1:m` to the list of values the operator will take on during the loop. This happens when the loop starts executing (note: you can use any array, and it'll be worked through column by column; `for letter='abcde';fprintf('%s\n',letter);end` works fine).

If you want to adjust how often your loop will be iterated through, I recommend using a `while` loop:

```
ct = 1;
maxIterations = 100;
success = false;
while ~success
   fprintf('iteration %i/%i\n',ct,maxIterations);
   ct = ct + 1;
   if ct == 2
      maxIterations == 1000;
   end

   if ct > maxIterations
       success = true;
   end
end
```

Comment: well, I tried this (similar to your idea)
`m = 100;
i = 0;
while(i < m)
    
    if (i == 2)
        m = 1000;
    end
    i = i+1;
end`

and it worked..!! Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not an expert but the for loop replace the m var with 100 in the first run and then it performs the loop as from 1 to 100 (not 1 to m) and it doesnt check every run what is m it knows that m is 100 and it runs until it reaches 100 if for example your script is like this:

```
<code>
m=100;
for i=1:m (m is 100)
 if(i==2)
  m=1000;
  for i=1:m (m is 1000)
    a=xyz;
   end
  end
end
</code>
```

Comment: I would say that a while loop is the solution here. You may not want to reiterate in case i==2...